# How to store an array of objects in Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can't find online how to store an array of objects so that the key "line_items" presents numbers for each menuItem with values for each menuItem corresponding to its own number. In other words, I need the numbers to come after line_items rather than the nested key so that each individual MenuItem object can be quickly referenced. I found online how to make it so each key has an array of values, but I need line_items to have an array of MenuItem objects. The following code crashes:

```
public func uploadTransactionData(_ menuItems: [MenuItem], balanceId: String, subTotal: Int, completion: @escaping (() -> ())) {
    guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { completion(); return }
    let utilitiesManager = UtilitiesManager()
    let timestamp = utilitiesManager.timestamp()
    let params: [String: Any] = ["date": "\(timestamp)",
        "balance_id": "\(balanceId)",
        "subtotal": "\(subTotal)",
        "user_id": "\(userId)",
        "line_items": menuItems
    ]
    Firestore.firestore().document("transaction_history/\(timestamp)").setData(params)
    { err in
        if let e = err {
            print("$-- error creating user \(e)")
            completion()
        } else {
            completion()
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the MenuItem model:

```
struct MenuItem {

let itemId: String
let name: String
var modifiers: [String]?
var photoName: String?
var photoUrl: String?
var quantity: Int
var price: Int
var sizeAddOnPrice: Int
var toppingsAddOnPrice: Int
let description: String
var size: String
let category: String

init(itemId: String, name: String, modifiers: [String]?, photoName: String?, photoUrl: String?, quantity: Int, price: Int, sizeAddOnPrice: Int, toppingsAddOnPrice: Int, description: String, size: String, category: String) {
    self.itemId = itemId
    self.name = name
    self.modifiers = modifiers
    self.photoName = photoName
    self.photoUrl = photoUrl
    self.quantity = quantity
    self.price = price
    self.sizeAddOnPrice = sizeAddOnPrice
    self.toppingsAddOnPrice = toppingsAddOnPrice
    self.description = description
    self.size = size
    self.category = category
}
```

Comment: Can you please add which error you are getting?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported type: _SwiftValue'

Comment: Firestore will never know what menuItem is. Please have a look here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types those are the data types supported by Firestore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem:**

Your app is crashing because you are trying to save user defined object `MenuItem` to Firestore. Firestore doesn't allow it. Firestore only supports [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) datatypes.

**Solution:**

You can convert your custom object `MenuItem` to Firestore supported datatypes.
You can do this by making following changes to your code.

1. Make `MenuItem` confirm to `Codable` protocol.

   ```
   struct MenuItem: Codable { 
        // Your code as it is.
   }
   ```
2. Make following changes to your `uploadTransactionData()` function:

   ```
   public func uploadTransactionData(_ menuItems: [MenuItem], balanceId: String, subTotal: Int, completion: @escaping (() -> ())) {
   let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { completion(); return }
   let utilitiesManager = UtilitiesManager()
   let timestamp =  utilitiesManager.timestamp()

   var list_menuItem = [Any]()
   for item in menuItems {
       do {
           let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(item)
           let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
           list_menuItem.append(jsonObject)
       }
       catch {
           // handle error
       }
   }

   let params: [String: Any] = ["date": "\(timestamp)",
       "balance_id": "\(balanceId)",
       "subtotal": "\(subTotal)",
       "user_id": "\(userId)",
       "line_items": list_menuItem
   ]


   Firestore.firestore().document("transaction_history/\(timestamp)").setData(params) 
       { err in
           if let e = err {
               print("$-- error creating user \(e)")
               completion()
           } else {
               completion()
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is because Firestore doesn't know how to save the value: menuItems

```
you can map it like this: "objectExample": [
    "a": 5,
    "b": [
        "nested": "foo"
    ]
]
```

or:

```
.setData([
"name": "Frank",
"favorites": [ "food": "Pizza", "color": "Blue", "subject": "recess" ],
"age": 12
])
```